# Lua: Globals not being passed to secondary file with "dofile"

Tags: lua, global-variables, global

I am using a modified version of [LDoc](https://github.com/AntumDeluge/LDoc/tree/custom) which generates HTML documentation for Lua source code.

I have modified LDoc to be able to import the `dofile` function into its configuration. However, globals that are set in the main configuration file (`config.ld`) are not being passed to sub-files with `dofile`.

Example config.ld:

```lua
dofile = import("dofile")

hello = "Hello world!"
dofile("auxf.ld")
```

auxf.ld:

```lua
print("Hello: " .. hello)
```

Result:

```
config.ld: auxf.ld:1: attempt to concatenate a nil value (global 'hello')
```

The problem must be something to do with LDoc's sandboxing, because if I execute directly from the Lua interpreter, it works.

<del>**Edit:** As Nifim pointed out, I can use `loadfile` which passes the environment to the secondary script. But any globals set in it are not accessible to the main script (`config.ld`).</del>

Comment: Try `loadfile` and pass in your environment as the second variable.

Comment: Is this the correct way to do it? `loadfile("auxf.ld", "t", _ENV`. If so, no error is output. But it doesn't print anything from `auxf.ld` either. It says second variable is supposed to be a string.

Comment: `loadfile` returns a function that needs to be called in order to execute the loaded code.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But now I have run onto another problem. Globals set in `auxf.ld` are not accessible from `config.ld`.

Comment: Oh wait, I'm sorry. I'm mistaken in that last comment. I had added a `do return end` statement in my `auxf.ld` that I had forgotten about. So it is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is credited to [Nifim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7396148/nifim).

The answer was to use `loadfile` & pass the environment in its parameters:

```lua
loadfile("auxf.ld", "t", _ENV)
```

I created a wrapper to be able to use `dofile`:

```lua
dofile = function(f)
  return loadfile(f, "t", _ENV)
end
```