# SOL / Lua + C++ Cannot access field

Tags: c++, lua

Sol & C++ embedding, cannot access usertype field

To start off with, I am pretty new to sol, however this is my implementation so far

```
namespace lua
{
    namespace lua_client
    {
        valve::ClientClass* GetAllClasses( )
        {
            auto client_class = csgo::base_client->GetAllClasses( );

            if ( !client_class )
                return nullptr;

            return client_class;
        }

        valve::ClientClass* GetClientClass( )
        {
            auto client_class = csgo::base_client->GetAllClasses( );

            while ( client_class )
            {
                if ( !strcmp( client_class->m_pNetworkName, "CBaseEntity" ) )
                    return client_class;

                client_class = client_class->m_pNext;
            }

            return nullptr;
        }

        void init( )
        {
            // setup our usertype(s)
            auto recv_prop_usertype = sol_state.new_usertype< valve::RecvProp >( "RecvProp", sol::constructors< valve::RecvProp( ) >( ) );
            recv_prop_usertype.set( "m_pVarName", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvProp::m_pVarName ) );
            recv_prop_usertype.set( "m_RecvType", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvProp::m_RecvType ) );
            recv_prop_usertype.set( "m_Flags", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvProp::m_Flags ) );
            recv_prop_usertype.set( "m_StringBufferSize", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvProp::m_StringBufferSize ) );
            recv_prop_usertype.set( "m_bInsideArray", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvProp::m_bInsideArray ) );
            recv_prop_usertype.set( "m_pExtraData", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvProp::m_pExtraData ) );
            recv_prop_usertype.set( "m_pArrayProp", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvProp::m_pArrayProp ) );
            recv_prop_usertype.set( "m_pDataTable", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvProp::m_pDataTable ) );
            recv_prop_usertype.set( "m_Offset", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvProp::m_Offset ) );
            recv_prop_usertype.set( "m_ElementStride", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvProp::m_ElementStride ) );
            recv_prop_usertype.set( "m_nElements", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvProp::m_nElements ) );
            recv_prop_usertype.set( "m_pParentArrayPropName", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvProp::m_pParentArrayPropName ) );

            auto recv_table_usertype = sol_state.new_usertype< valve::RecvTable >( "RecvTable", sol::constructors< valve::RecvTable( ) >( ) );
            recv_table_usertype.set( "m_pProps", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvTable::m_pProps ) ); // BUG!!!: attempt to index a nil value (local 'prop')
            recv_table_usertype.set( "m_nProps", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvTable::m_nProps ) );
            recv_table_usertype.set( "m_pNetTableName", sol::readonly( &valve::RecvTable::m_pNetTableName ) );

            auto client_class_usertype = sol_state.new_usertype< valve::ClientClass >( "ClientClass" );
            client_class_usertype.set( "m_pNetworkName", sol::readonly( &valve::ClientClass::m_pNetworkName ) );
            client_class_usertype.set( "m_pRecvTable", sol::readonly( &valve::ClientClass::m_pRecvTable ) );
            client_class_usertype.set( "m_pNext", sol::readonly( &valve::ClientClass::m_pNext ) );
            client_class_usertype.set( "m_ClassID", sol::readonly( &valve::ClientClass::m_ClassID ) );

            // setup our table(s)
            auto client_table = sol_state.create_table( "client" );
            client_table[ "GetAllClasses" ] = GetAllClasses;
            client_table[ "GetClientClass" ] = GetClientClass;
        }
    }
}
```

Attempting to access it as so

```
-- example script to dump netvars

local client_class = client.GetAllClasses( )

-- is clientclass still valid?
while client_class do
    local table = client_class.m_pRecvTable

    -- do we have a valid table?
    if table ~= nil then
        print( "" .. table.m_ClassID )
    end

    client_class = client_class.m_pNext
end
```

This is the following error produced:
[sol2] An error occurred and has been passed to an error handler: sol: runtime error: test.lua:11: attempt to concatenate a nil value (field 'm_ClassID')
stack traceback:
test.lua:11: in main chun

Calling the same function in c++ side works fine

Any ideas? Thank you

Using lua 5.4 & sol2

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68715974/lua-globals-not-being-passed-to-secondary-file-with-dofile

Comment: Hey @jspcal, I appreciate it but it seems that's not entirely relevant to what library I'm using. It seems the global environment is getting setup correctly because I can access 'client' still, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution.  I wrote the script in haste and I was attempting to access `m_ClassID` from table, which doesn't have that member.

Switching `table.m_ClassID` to `client_class.m_ClassID` did the trick

Thanks anyways everyone.